# Flutter app doesn't build when I add google-sign-in or firebase dependencies to yaml file

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

When I add Google sign in or firebase dependencies in my yaml file, the app crashes. It crashes in iOS and does not build in Android.

I updated my flutter, I added the required line in the build.gradle file. The example memechat doesn't even run. In the example app that's created by default, it works before I add the dependencies and works once I take them out.

When I don't have "google_sign_in: ^0.2.1" in my yaml file, it works fine.  When I add it, it doesn't build and I get the output below about "Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'."

If it add these firebase dependencies and take out the google-signin on, it doesn't work either and I can see a similar output.
    firebase_analytics: ^0.0.2
    firebase_auth: ^0.0.2
    firebase_database: ^0.0.4
    firebase_storage: ^0.0.2

Has anyone run into something similar?

```
flutter build -v apk
[      +17 ms] [/Users/ib/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[      +28 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[            ] origin/alpha
[            ] [/Users/ib/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[       +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[            ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[            ] [/Users/ib/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[      +16 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[            ] d36e2f6191793de66e0a132ad8c86885829bc6b2
[            ] [/Users/ib/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[      +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[            ] 8 days ago
[     +144 ms] Running "flutter packages get" in myapp...
[       +2 ms] [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/] /Users/ib/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub --verbosity=warning get --no-precompile
[    +1303 ms] Found plugin google_sign_in at /Users/ib/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-0.2.1/
[     +221 ms] Using gradle from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle.
[       +9 ms] Running 'gradle assembleRelease'...
[       +2 ms] [android/] /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle -Ptarget=lib/main.dart assembleRelease
[    +2206 ms] Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
[      +43 ms] The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
[            ]  at build_73mnt1bv3vfkr8ldx3go0eh12$_run_closure2.doCall(/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/android/build.gradle:22)
[     +342 ms] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:extractProguardFiles
[            ] :app:preReleaseBuild
[       +1 ms] :app:checkReleaseManifest
[            ] :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:preProfileBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:checkReleaseManifest
[            ] :google_sign_in:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
[       +7 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[      +22 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +8 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:prepareReleaseDependencies
[       +7 ms] :google_sign_in:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
[       +3 ms] :google_sign_in:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
[      +46 ms] :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
[      +13 ms] :google_sign_in:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
[      +11 ms] :google_sign_in:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[      +10 ms] :google_sign_in:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[       +3 ms] :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
[       +7 ms] :google_sign_in:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :google_sign_in:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :google_sign_in:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[       +5 ms] :google_sign_in:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
[       +3 ms] :google_sign_in:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
[       +3 ms] :google_sign_in:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +3 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +5 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +4 ms] :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[      +10 ms] :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +9 ms] :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +2 ms] :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1101Library UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:prepareIoFlutterPluginsGooglesigninGoogle_sign_in10SNAPSHOTLibrary UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:prepareReleaseDependencies
[       +7 ms] :app:compileReleaseAidl
[      +12 ms] :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
[       +6 ms] :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[       +1 ms] :app:flutterDependenciesRelease UP-TO-DATE
[   +15022 ms] :app:flutterBuildRelease
[       +2 ms] :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
[       +4 ms] :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[      +10 ms] :app:mergeReleaseAssets
[      +63 ms] :app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease
[       +5 ms] :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
[     +969 ms] :app:mergeReleaseResources
[      +69 ms] :app:processReleaseManifest
[     +309 ms] :app:processReleaseResources
[       +1 ms] :app:generateReleaseSources
[      +20 ms] :app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
[       +7 ms] :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[            ] :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
[     +234 ms] :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
[            ] :app:compileReleaseSources
[     +511 ms] :app:lintVitalRelease
[            ] :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
[     +781 ms] :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
[      +20 ms] :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
[       +1 ms] ProGuard, version 5.2.1
[       +1 ms] Reading input...
[            ] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm-release/flutter.jar] (filtered)
[     +186 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-auth-base/11.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +16 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-core-utils/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +25 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/11.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +40 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-auth/11.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +13 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-media-compat/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +39 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-fragment/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +22 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef/guava-20.0.jar] (filtered)
[     +362 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/multidex/1.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[       +2 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-tasks/11.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[       +3 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-compat/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +73 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.2.0/support-annotations-25.2.0.jar] (filtered)
[       +4 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-core-ui/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +18 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/25.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[            ] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/11.0.1/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[      +29 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin/google_sign_in/1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
[       +1 ms] Reading program jar [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/jars/2/1f/main.jar] (filtered)
[      +53 ms] Reading program directory [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/folders/2/1f/main] (filtered)
[            ] Reading program directory [/Users/ib/IdeaProjects/myapp/build/app/intermediates/classes/release] (filtered)
[       +7 ms] Reading library jar [/Users/ib/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar]
[     +941 ms] Reading library jar [/Users/ib/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.HttpResponseCache]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
[      +14 ms] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
[       +4 ms] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory]
[            ] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
[       +3 ms] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
[       +5 ms] Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
[       +1 ms]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[       +6 ms] Initializing...
[       +6 ms] Warning: com.google.common.util.concurrent.FuturesGetChecked$GetCheckedTypeValidatorHolder$ClassValueValidator$1: can't find superclass or interface java.lang.ClassValue
[     +134 ms] Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[            ] Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[            ] Warning: com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[            ] Warning: com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
```

....

```
[            ] Warning: com.google.common.xml.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
[            ] Warning: com.google.common.xml.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
[     +226 ms] Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager
[            ] Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy
[       +1 ms] Note: com.google.protobuf.zzc: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry
[            ] Note: com.google.protobuf.zzd: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.Extension
[            ] Note: com.google.protobuf.zze: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.io.Memory
[            ] Note: com.google.protobuf.zze: can't find dynamically referenced class org.robolectric.Robolectric
[      +83 ms] Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_ID' dynamically
[       +1 ms]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { java.lang.String MODULE_ID; }'
[       +2 ms] Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'MODULE_VERSION' dynamically
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { int MODULE_VERSION; }'
[       +2 ms] Note: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule accesses a declared field 'sClassLoader' dynamically
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader { java.lang.ClassLoader sClassLoader; }'
[      +29 ms] Note: com.google.common.cache.Striped64 accesses a declared field 'base' dynamically
[       +1 ms]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.cache.Striped64 { long base; }'
[       +3 ms] Note: com.google.common.cache.Striped64 accesses a declared field 'busy' dynamically
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.cache.Striped64 { int busy; }'
[       +2 ms] Note: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell accesses a declared field 'value' dynamically
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.add { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aeb { java.lang.String value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.MoreObjects$ToStringHelper$ValueHolder { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper$ValueHolder { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Suppliers$ExpiringMemoizingSupplier { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Suppliers$MemoizingSupplier { java.lang.Object value; }'
```

....

```
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo { java.lang.String value; }'
[      +64 ms] Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper accesses a declared field 'waiters' dynamically
[       +1 ms]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture { com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Waiter waiters; }'
[       +3 ms] Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper accesses a declared field 'listeners' dynamically
[       +1 ms]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture { com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Listener listeners; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService { java.util.List listeners; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager$ServiceManagerState { java.util.List listeners; }'
[       +1 ms] Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper accesses a declared field 'value' dynamically
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.add { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aeb { java.lang.String value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.MoreObjects$ToStringHelper$ValueHolder { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper$ValueHolder { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Suppliers$ExpiringMemoizingSupplier { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.base.Suppliers$MemoizingSupplier { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$WriteThroughEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell { long value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.Count { int value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap$Node { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$StrongKeyStrongValueEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$WeakKeyStrongValueEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$WriteThroughEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.Ordering$IncomparableValueException { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.Tables$ImmutableCell { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$Reference { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap$RangeMapEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.graph.MapRetrievalCache$CacheEntry { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger { int value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong { long value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicDouble { long value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ImmediateFuture$ImmediateSuccessfulCheckedFuture { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ImmediateFuture$ImmediateSuccessfulFuture { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.icu.util.Output { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.icu.util.RangeValueIterator$Element { int value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.icu.util.ValueIterator$Element { java.lang.Object value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableBoolean { boolean value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableByte { byte value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableChar { char value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableDouble { double value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableFloat { float value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableInt { int value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableLong { long value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.util.MutableShort { short value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'android.view.animation.Animation$Description { float value; }'
[            ]       Maybe this is library field 'java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo { java.lang.String value; }'
[     +366 ms] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
[      +88 ms] Note: there were 1 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
[            ]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
[            ]       (using '-keep').
[            ]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
[            ] Note: there were 6 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
[            ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[            ]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
[            ] Note: there were 9 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
[            ]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
[            ]       (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
[            ]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
[            ] Warning: there were 2125 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[            ]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[            ]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[       +1 ms]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[            ]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
[       +4 ms] Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[      +16 ms] :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
[      +10 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[            ] * What went wrong:
[            ] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
[            ] > Job failed, see logs for details
[            ] * Try:
[            ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[            ] BUILD FAILED
[            ] Total time: 24.766 secs
[     +556 ms] "flutter apk" took 27,085ms.
Gradle build failed: 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:29)
#1      buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:255)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:192)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:83)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:55)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:210)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      BuildSubCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build.dart:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:156)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:277)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:206)
#12     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:161)
#14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120)
#18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1001)
#19     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1467)
#20     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#21     run (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:114)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:67)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     main (file:///Users/ib/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:16)
#24     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:263)
#25     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:151)


[     +263 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 256ms
[            ] exiting with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to `firebase_auth: ^0.1.0`. I don't think that `firebase_auth: 0.0.2` is compatible with `google_sign_in: ^0.2.1` because they are linking against different versions of the Android libraries.

The changes in these updates was [announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/gpstLldeTd4) on the developer mailing list recently.

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11036) to make this easier.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I then tried to install gradle separately, everything broke, even the default start app didn't work anymore.  I tried changing settings, reinstall Android Studio, try more settings, reinstall Android Studio again, try more settings, reinstall flutter, then I got it back to the state when I wrote this question. Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: For posterity, I finally got it to work. I'm not sure if it was the "flutter upgrade" or restarting IntelliJ or just ignoring it for a while and then getting back to it.  I definitely use the newer versions.  Thanks for the guidance!